# Sending data from SAP S/4HANA to SAP data hub on events trigger

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, s4hana

I want to transfer my data from SAP S/4HANA to SAP data hub whenever lets say a purchase order gets created. these seems like a message queue problem but I am not sure what to use.

So whenever there is a order creation S/4HANA sends notification, which can be received by SAP enterprise messaging queue, but from that queue I am not sure how to send the data to datahub. Can datahub provide a SAP EM consumer who will get the message from the EM queue. I can see datahub has kafka consumer but does it support SAP enterprise messaging ?